# Event stop firing in a loop

Tags: vb.net

I have 2 subs like below, and when I make a loop with 1000 iterations and capturePicture() in it. after 700 iterations the event is not raised anymore.
Can anyone help me?

```
 Public Sub capturePicture()
        Try
            AddHandler capturePic.FrameEvent2, AddressOf CaptureDone
            capturePic.GrapImg()
            Threading.Thread.Sleep(270)
        Catch ex As Exception
            RemoveHandler capturePic.FrameEvent2, AddressOf CaptureDone
        End Try
  End Sub


 Private Sub CaptureDone(ByVal e As Bitmap)
        Try
            Me.PictureBox1.Image = e
            PictureBox1.Image.Save(MakeFileNameWithAutoIncrement(MakeFolderNameForCurrentDate(MyFolderName) + "\" + MyTimeStampDatumVrijeme() + "_" + Filename4Cam + "-CAM1(" + CamEvent + ").JPG"), System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)
            RemoveHandler capturePic.FrameEvent2, AddressOf CaptureDone
        Catch ex As Exception
            RemoveHandler capturePic.FrameEvent2, AddressOf CaptureDone
        End Try 
    End Sub
```

Comment: What is the purpose of the `Thread.Sleep` call?

Comment: if we remove thread.sleep we take only one picture.
thread.sleep enables us to run the loop normally.

Answer (score 1):

.NET has a *very* nice and reliable way to tell you that there's something wrong.  But that stops working when you catch Exception and don't do anything to let the user (or you) know what is wrong.  Your catch statement is hiding all kinds of serious problems, like OutOfMemory.

Debug + Exceptions, check "Common Language Runtime Exceptions" and run your program.